# MongoDB as Real-time database

Tags: mongodb, firebase, ionic3, real-time, google-cloud-firestore

I have an experience with real-time database firestore. Currently, I'm working on Ionic 3 app with MongoDB. On that app, we have to use pull to refresh feature to update the latest content. But if we have real-time DB then we don't need to have such feature. Due to above issue, my client now wants to use firestore. But the key problem where we have is data migration. That is MongoDB to firestore. Currently, this app is in production (i.e. app stores) and having over 500+ users. Because of that converting app to firestore will be a very difficult task. So my question here is, Can't we use real-time DB features with MongoDB?

***Note:*** I use `Nodejs/Express` as Restfull api.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What's your backend? How about using [socket.io](https://socket.io/)?

Since you're using MongoDB and Express already, here's a sample:

**Server file:**

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/api/add', function(req, res){
    db.collection('quotes').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)

        // send everyone the added data
        io.emit('ADDED_DATA', req.body);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

**in your client:**

```js
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

const socket = io('http://localhost:3030'); //ip and port of server

socket.on('ADDED_DATA', (data) => {
    // manipulate data
    // push to current list
    // or whatever you want
});
```

Comment: https://sibeeshpassion.com/creating-a-chat-application-in-node-js-with-express-mongodb-mongoose-and-socket-io/

Comment: I know about that doc. But where they have mentioned about real-time feature? @Satya

Comment: read , and then modify your queries / db / indexes to let mongo work as realtime db

Comment: This is really nice +1. Thanks. Do you have nice reference to learn more about it @sorxrob

Comment: This doesn't scale across instances though? For example if you deployed node on App Engine it would only alert some users and not all of them.

Comment: My conclusion from this discussion is than mongo cannot work as realtime,and this is really bad,firebase beat them.Solution with sockets is only simulation and very difficult to maintain on frontend(React).